# What's mean from expression InterfaceName(0xABCD.....) , oxABCD is an contract address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, grammar

Here is an example i see in cource code off bunny finance   https://github.com/PancakeBunny-finance/Bunny/blob/main/contracts/vaults/venus/VaultVenusBridgeOwner.sol#L52

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create references to contracts:

1. Deploy a new instance with `Contr c = new Contr(possible_constructor_arguments);`
2. Reference a contract which has already been deployed: `Contr c = Contr(address_of_contract);`. Here `Contr` can either be an interface or the contract implementation (if you have its source code).

So, to answer your question, the line is referencing an existing implementation of the contract at address 0xABCD. It uses an interface so that the interface's functionality is available for the reference (so you can actually call the contract's functionality).

Comment: Very helpful and important for solidity beginer, tks sir.